# Codeigniter и join

Tags: php, join, codeigniter

Есть две таблицы:

sources: столбцы id, time и пр.
и items: столбцы id, sourceid и пр.

Далее в модели делаю следующее:

```
    $this->db->join('sources','sources.id = items.sourceid');
    $query = $this->db->get('items');
    return $query->result_array();
```

Модель возвращает массив, в котором нет элементов items.id. Как к ним обратиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('sources.id AS sources_id, и так далее...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('items.*, sources.*, items.id as item_id')
$this->db->join('sources','sources.id = items.sourceid');
$query = $this->db->get('items');
return $query->result_array();
```